# Assembly.LoadFrom how behaves on multi version dll

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I've a dll with 2.0.0.1 version in one server which can be downloaded by accessing http://someipaddress/assembly/test.dll and I'm having another application which need to download this test.dll and have to access those methods.

When surfing for this, i've got three different methods to do,
1. Assembly.LoadFrom()
2. Assembly.LoadFile()
3. Assembly.Load()

I've tried `Assembly.LoadFrom("http://someipaddress/assembly/test.dll")`

Now i've replaced test.dll with 2.0.0.2 version and
What will happen the application download 2.0.0.2 test.dll and already downloaded test.dll 2.0.0.1.
Application which dll will refer?
Will it use existing test.dll 2.0.0.1 since its already downloaded while accessing test.dll 2.0.0.2?

Please suggest on this.

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you are fretting about, hard to guess what "already downloaded" could mean and why it matters.  You'll have to rebuild the app so it uses the updated reference assembly.  Or provide a bindingRedirect in the app.config file to say that 2.0.0.2 is okay.  If you don't then the expected and logical thing happens when an app gets the wrong DLL.  Try it.

Answer (score 0):

It'll depend on how you're referencing the assembly. By default if there's no binding redirect, your new dll will cause an exception. You can get around this by specifying an binding redirect rule in your application's configuration file like so;

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Test" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.2" newVersion="2.0.0.2" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

But you'd need to update it upon getting the new version of the dll.